# Landau & Lifshitz 'Mechanics': How is the potential energy related to additive property of Lagrangian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, linear-systems

By additive property of Lagrangian, I mean following:
Let a system consist of two parts A and B which are not interacting with each other, so A and B will have separate Lagrangians $$L_a,L_b$$ and in limit where the distance between the parts becomes so large that their interaction can be neglected:
$$ L = L_a+L_b$$

> The potential energy is defined only to within an additive constant, which has no effect on the equations of motion. This is a particular case of the non-uniqueness of the Lagrangian discussed at the end of Section 2. The most usual way of choosing this constant is such that the potential energy tends to zero as the distance between the articles tend to infinity.

I understand how multiplication of the Lagrangian by an arbitrary constant has no effect on equations of motion and the Lagrangian for a system is not unique, but how is that idea related to this? The only similarity I see is that any interaction can basically be neglected as distance tends to infinity.

Apologies if the question seems dumb. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The quoted text does not reference any subsystems or additivity in the sense which you describe above it.  It simply says that if $L' = L+const$, then $L' \neq L$ but they produce the same EoM.

Comment: I agree with J. Murray - the quoted passage says nothing about the additivity of two Lagrangians. It's talking about the addition of a constant onto a Lagrangian.

Comment: Oh thanks, I see it now.  I misunderstood what the passage was referencing to.